# ¿Cómo capturar una cadena de caracteres desde donde se indica hasta el primer punto seguido de un salto de línea?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, substring

```py
import re

x = """44
5844 44554  Hi hi!   , sahhashash; asakjas. jjksakjaskjas.
ooooooppkkk"""

#ambas inician después del último salto de línea que tienen dentro de su rango de captura(lo cual es un error)
# ((?:\w+)?)   ---> con un grupo de captura este patrón puede capturar una subcadena de caracteres alfanuméricos (mayúsculas y minúsculas) hasta que se toma con un espacio, una coma o un punto
# ((?:\w\s*)+)   ---> este patrón es similar al anterior pero no se detiene al encontrar espacios
regex_patron_m1 = r"\s*((?:\w+)?) \s*\¿?(?:del |de |)\s*((?:\w\s*)+)\s*\??"

m1 = re.search(regex_patron_m1, x, re.IGNORECASE) #Con esto valido la regex haber si entra o no en el bloque de code

if m1:
    word, association = m1.groups()
    
    print(repr(word)) #imprime la subcadena capturada por el primer grupo de captura
    print(repr(association)) #imprime la subcadena capturada por el segundo grupo de captura
```

El resultado que obtengo con estos dos patrones, es este y es bastante incorrecto ya que ni siquiera inicia la captura en el lugar correcto

```
'5844'
'44554  Hi hi'
```

---

¿Qué debo modificar para obtener lo siguiente? ya que no entiendo por qué ambos grupos de captura comienzan su captura después de la nueva línea. En este caso quiero que se detenga en el primer salto de linea encontrado o con un punto y aparte, que podria ser algo asi `".[\s|]*\n*"` o `".\n*"`

```
'44'
'5844 44554  Hi hi!   , sahhashash; asakjas. jjksakjaskjas.'
```

---

Y si no quisiese que se detuviese en el salto de linea, para obtener algo asi, que deberia modificar?

```
'44'
'5844 44554  Hi hi!   , sahhashash; asakjas. jjksakjaskjas.
ooooooppkkk'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solución:

```
subcadena = x[:x.index(".\n")+1]
```

`index()` te da el indice donde se encuentra un punto seguido de un new-line. Con eso puedes extraer un slice desde el comienzo hasta el punto aparte.

`subcadena` incluye hasta el punto, pero no incluye el `\n`.

#### Demo

```
x = """44
5844 44554  Hi hi!   , sahhashash; asakjas. jjksakjaskjas.
ooooooppkkk"""

subcadena = x[:x.index(".\n")+1]
print(subcadena)
```

produce:

```
44
5844 44554  Hi hi!   , sahhashash; asakjas. jjksakjaskjas.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: el problema es que son 2 grupos de captura diferentes, o sea "44" y luego "5844 44554  Hi hi!   , sahhashash; asakjas. jjksakjaskjas."

Comment: @MatiasNicolasRodriguez. Puedes aplicarle la expresión regular para sacar los grupos, sin peligro de pasarse del punto aparte.